# How to get rid of white flashes on navigation using @react-navigation/native and @react-navigation/native-stack

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v6

Whenever I navigate to another screen,the screen flashes white as the screen navigated to seems to fade in. I built the app to both have a light and dark mode; this would have been fine for light mode but in dark mode the white flash is annoying and I have no idea on how on how to get rid of it.

My App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack'

import LScreen from './src/screens/LScreen'
import HScreen from './src/screens/HScreen'
import CPScreen from './src/screens/CPScreen'

export default function App() {
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="LScreen" component={LScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="HScreen" component={HScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="CPScreen" component={CPScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

Can someone kindly advise on how I can overcome this challenge or an alternative to this navigation method

Comment: follow the issue on Github. https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/9883

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove animation during navigation. That's all!

Answer (score 2):

I created a similar project to test and here is the solution I came up with.

Try to use:

```
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack'
```

Rather than:

```
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack'
```

With yours, I was seeing the same delay/white between screens. When I changed to the other, I saw no white screen. I tested this with a yellow and black background.

I created a basic light/dark theme using `React Native Paper`, and there were no issues there either.

Answer (score 2):

Import DarkTheme from "@react-navigation/native" and set the theme prop on NavigationContainer to DarkTheme
Code below

```js
<NavigationContainer theme={DarkTheme}>
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen name="LScreen" component={LScreen} />
  <Stack.Screen name="HScreen" component={HScreen} />
  <Stack.Screen name="CPScreen" component={CPScreen} />
</Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to import '@react-navigation/native' adding to 'DefaultTheme' like so:

```
import { NavigationContainer, DefaultTheme } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

Inside this `DefaultTheme` there is a an array that has the background color `rgb(242, 242, 242)`. This is the white flash you see. We will set this to some other value.

Create this constant:

```
const MyTheme = { 
  ...DefaultTheme, 
  colors: {
    ...DefaultTheme.colors, 
    background: '//whatever color you want it to be',
  }
};
```

Then you set the `theme` property on the `NavigationContainer` component like this:

```
<NavigationContainer theme={MyTheme}>
// Your stacks
</NavigationContainer>
```

This is the documentation to guide you:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/themes/